# How to retrieve current time of HTML5 audio player as it's playing live? (mediaelement.js)

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using the HTML5 audio tag on a website. I need to pull the current time of the track as it plays, preferably in seconds. Eventually, I will need to use this time to interact with other elements on the page, but can not seem to figure out how to retrieve current time of the track in real time as it plays.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this tutorial help? http://designmodo.com/audio-player/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the audio player. The events are all listed here http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_ref_eventattributes.asp under 'Media Events'. When you create the MediaElement player you can add the eventlisteners under the 'success' function.

Using this method ensures it works in the Flash fallback also.

```
mediaElement = new MediaElementPlayer('audio',{
//options etc

// method that fires when the Flash or Silverlight object is ready
success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {   

   // add event listeners
   mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
       onVideoTimeUpdate(e);
   }, false);

   mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
       onVideoPaused(e);
   }, false);

   mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
       onVideoPlayed(e);
   }, false);

   //etc
}

function onVideoTimeUpdate(e){
    //something to do on the time update event
}
```

If you are just using HTML5 audio tag you can add the event listener like so

```
myaudio=document.getElementById("audio1");
myaudio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e)
  {
     //something to do on the time update event
   }
);
```

Comment: Here is the w3c spec for events http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec//media-elements.html#event-definitions. Excuse my ignorance but I am not really sure why w3school is not valid?

Comment: w3schools is a good place to learn how to do it on the WRONG way. A lot of info on the website is wrong and most of the examples are full of bad practices. The content was probably good 5-7 years ago but the development practices taught by the website are really outdated.

Comment: http://w3fools.com is a website that claims to describe some of the problems with W3Schools

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: hope you found these links help full

Comment: All very interesting, especially this 'W3Schools.com is not affiliated with the W3C in any way.', thanks. I will avoid w3schools in the future!